# Question about dynamic arrays

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays

I am currently playing around with Solidity and dynamic arrays. I have the following code:

```
contract Test{
    int256[] public test;

    function setTest(int256 b) public{
        test.push(b);
    }

    function setTest2(uint256 a, int256 b) public {
        test[a] = b;
    }
}
```

I executed the code in remix. When I call setTest(1) and call the getter test(0), the output is 1. If I do the same with setTest2(0, 1) and call the getter afterwards, the value does not seem to be saved. I don't understand why. Could someone explain what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

---

I realized that my question is not really clear and I will ask the question here and this time more clear. Thanks for the other answers already.

I call the function `setTest2(0, 1)` and call the getter afterwards, remix shows me that the value at position 0 is 0 and not 1. 
When I call the `setTest(2)` function and call the getter afterwards, the value 2 is at position 0 of the array and not at position 1. This means that the value of the first call has not been saved. Why?

Comment: If you call `setTest2(0,1)` on an array of a length of 0, it won't work.

Comment: It's length is 0? How come? Is it somewhere in the docs? I can't find it...

Comment: If you didn't push anything before, yeah, your array is empty, and trying to set some value at whatever position will fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Dynamic arrays, you can't use DynamicArray[a] = b, if position a is not yet filled by the push function. If it would be a Static array, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setTest(1)`, your array contains `1` at the position `0`. After that, you call `setTest2(0,1)`, which sets at the position `0` the value `1`.

The value is the same, so you won't notice any difference. If you call `setTest2(0,5)`, you will see it will be different.

Comment: Thanks and it makes sense. I realized that my question did not cover the initial question. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit.
I just checked and it seems that calling `setTest()` on a position of the array, that hasn't been initialized previously doesn't work. So in otherwords, you can use that to change a value, but not add a new one.
That's why your `setTest()` always starts at the beginning. You first need to push a new element to a position in order for `setTest2()` to have any effect.

Comment: Yea, you are right and it makes sense. I realized that my question did not cover the initial question. I edited it.